# Google play store now forcing adware on my android

Tags: google-play-store

I was being swamped by google play store adware, redirecting my phone to the google play store and various downloads.  It happened any time I activated anything on my phone...  opened a folder.. redirected to google play store.  Recieved a phone call; sometimes I could not clear all the redirects to different apps, usually games or phone tools, until the caller hung up.   Open messages, get redirected, etc.  Cleared the cache and everthing, and it was all good until I accepted the terms and conditions for the google play store, then they were all back.

BAD ANDROID!!

How can I continue to use the Google play store, yet not be harassed all the time to download and install this and that app? It's so difficult to clear the layers of google play store offers that its actually acting like malware.

Please help.

Ren421

Comment: Play Store doesn't do that! Your phone must be having a malware  doing all of this stuff. Could you tell us where you're directed to in Play Store? Is it the front page of Store or a particular app? Do give us the list of all the third party apps you've? Also, if you're convinced that it is an adware then consider using an ad blocker.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have some kind of malware on your phone. Google Play doesn't acts like this.

You should try a factory reset and see if this solves your problem.

By the way, this will **ERASE ALL YOUR DATA** like photos, sms...and apps data so you'll have to log in again on every app.

Hope it helps!